# Am I doing the correct thing in responding to this user?

Tags: discussion

So I started commenting on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237227/python-text-widget-adding-several-images-and-references) last week to try and get clarification. It wasn't something I was particularly on the ball about and so some time passed between each comment.

The user has since found a solution for their question however they are rather displeased with the fact that their question was downvoted and put on hold choosing to lash out at the community rather than improve their post.

Them being new to the community I thought I'd chip in and explain, the user has reacted rather poorly to this.

I've never dealt with this kind of situation and wanted to know whether I'm handling it with an appropriate response or whether I should just flag the post with a message for the moderators and walk away?

Comment: Ugh, no. Lots of abusive and pointless comments there that will be evaporating shortly. When a user is beyond the point of help or listening to reason, just flag for moderator attention, please.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you, I'll follow that guidance in future.

Comment: I was expecting to see a heavily-downvoted question, based on the comments. Imagine my surprise when I see it has gotten *one* downvote. Some people just lose their minds when their question gets downvoted. I don't have an explanation for it. A better thing for them to do would be to consider why others might find it unclear. No point in letting people waste your time or insult you. There are others who will be more appreciative of your help.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't understand why people join a community asking for help only to criticise the way the community they **voluntarily joined seeking free advice** works.

Comment: the one line solution... looks like copied from somewhere else

Comment: Well, SO is based on a pretty difficult premise.  Most questioners assume it is a site to get help with their coding issue.  But most visitors prefer the best solution to a programming problem.  Which quite often has nothing to do with what the OP is trying to pursue.  The vast majority of problems are self-induced.  Telling them they are doing it wrong, or did not provide info to see the underlying problem, is very rarely appreciated.  You should really only try once, if at all.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll take that on board, thank you